SyntaxError During Application Deployment Due to Invalid JSON Response
This error indicates that the application is receiving an unexpected HTML response (likely an error page or web server response), instead of a valid JSON payload, during an authentication service operation.
Notably, this issue does not occur when deploying other containers.
What I have tried to resolve:
Added http_uri http_settings in graylog.conf.
Graylog.conf
data_dir = /usr/share/graylog/data
node_id_file = /usr/share/graylog/data/journal/node-id
root_username = ${GRAYLOG_ROOT_USERNAME}
root_password = ${GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD}
password_secret = ${GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET}
root_password_sha2 = ${GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2}
root_email =
root_timezone = UTC

# Rotation strategy settings
rotation_strategy = ${GRAYLOG_ROTATION_STRATEGY}
rotation_strategy_settings_rotation_period = ${GRAYLOG_ROTATION_STRATEGY_SETTINGS_ROTATION_PERIOD}

# Retention strategy settings
retention_strategy = ${GRAYLOG_RETENTION_STRATEGY}
retention_strategy_settings_index_lifecycle_max_number_of_indices = ${GRAYLOG_RETENTION_STRATEGY_SETTINGS_INDEX_LIFECYCLE_MAX_NUMBER_OF_INDICES}
retention_strategy_settings_index_lifecycle_delete_index_max_age = ${GRAYLOG_RETENTION_STRATEGY_SETTINGS_INDEX_LIFECYCLE_DELETE_INDEX_MAX_AGE}

# Index lifecycle settings
58time_size_optimizing_retention_min_lifetime = ${GRAYLOG_TIME_SIZE_OPTIMIZING_RETENTION_MIN_LIFETIME}
time_size_optimizing_retention_max_lifetime = ${GRAYLOG_TIME_SIZE_OPTIMIZING_RETENTION_MAX_LIFETIME}

# Rotate empty index set setting
rotate_empty_index_set = false

http_bind_address = 0.0.0.0:9000
elasticsearch_hosts = ${GRAYLOG_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS}
elasticsearch_discovery_enabled = false
allow_leading_wildcard_searches = false
allow_highlighting = false
output_batch_size = 500
output_flush_interval = 1
output_fault_count_threshold = 5
output_fault_penalty_seconds = 30
processbuffer_processors = 5
outputbuffer_processors = 3
processor_wait_strategy = blocking
ring_size = 65536
inputbuffer_ring_size = 65536
inputbuffer_processors = 2
inputbuffer_wait_strategy = blocking
message_journal_enabled = true
message_journal_dir = /usr/share/graylog/data/journal
message_journal_max_age = ${GRAYLOG_MESSAGE_JOURNAL_MAX_AGE}
message_journal_max_size = ${GRAYLOG_MESSAGE_JOURNAL_MAX_SIZE}
lb_recognition_period_seconds = 3
mongodb_uri = ${GRAYLOG_MONGODB_URI}
mongodb_max_connections = 1000
mongodb_threads_allowed_to_block_multiplier = 5

# Email transport
transport_email_enabled = false
transport_email_hostname =
transport_email_port = 2587
transport_email_use_auth = true
transport_email_use_tls = true
transport_email_use_ssl = false
transport_email_auth_username =
transport_email_auth_password =
transport_email_subject_prefix = [graylog]
transport_email_from_email =
gc_warning_threshold = 1s
content_packs_dir = /usr/share/graylog/data/contentpacks
content_packs_auto_load = grok-patterns.json
proxied_requests_thread_pool_size = 32

